# Seleccionar todos los checkbox del historial de chrome (retornados por una búsqueda especifica) de manera automática con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chrome

Quiero borrar todo el historial de youtube en mi pc, pero resulta que chrome no tiene la opción "seleccionar todo" para eliminar el historial de una pagina especifica

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCIEE.png]

Estoy intentando hacerlo con Javascript, el problema es que soy un neófito en este lenguaje, he investigado un poco y llegue a armar el código a continuación que lo único que hace es retornar undefined en la consola de desarrollo de chrome, he buscado como acceder a un id que esta dentro de un div que esta dentro de otro div y asi pero no he encontrado nada hasta el momento, **ese es uno de los limitantes a la hora de resolver el problema, no saber cómo acceder al id=** *"checkbox"* (inspeccionando los id llegue a la conclusion de que estan anidados de la sgte manera: **history>items>item-container>checkbox**)

```
//aqui se supone se guardarían todos los los checkbox
const demoClasses = document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox');
// intente con la linea a continuación que retornó *undefined*, ni idea si estoy accediendo o no
//const demoClasses = document.querySelectorAll('#history#items#item-container#checkbox');

demoClasses.forEach(element => { //recorro el array(?) 
  element.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true'); //edito el atributo para que se marque el checkbox
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Estoy asumiendo que tienes idea de cómo funcionan los navegadores. Lo que estás intentando es manipular datos de chrome, no de un documento. Javascript en su propiedad 'document' está accediendo al arbol DOM. Pero nada de esto tiene que ver, tú quieres eliminar tu historial de búsqueda **de chrome** pero javascript no tiene acceso a ese tipo de datos.

Si quiere comprobarlo desde otra perspectiva...
[La misma pregunta en el foro original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

Comment: Te dare un +1, porque haz dicho algo totalmente cierto, y esto deberia responder a la pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta que compartes es mucho más simplona y poco elaborada, me asustaste xd. Lo que yo quiero solo es automatizar la selección de checkbox para no hacerlo de manera manual (serían 1248 clicks a "mano") a través de código javascript. El procedimiento de borrado lo hace chrome luego de presionar el botón delete (el se encarga de borrar lo que yo he especificado de sus servidores pero eso es backend yo quiero usar "trucos" en el frontend para evitarme el tedio y aprender algo nuevo). Estoy casi seguro de que se puede hacer

Comment: No, no se puede hacer.

Comment: Y la razón por la que no se puede es porque provocaría grave problemas de seguridad. Eso permitiría a cualquier sitio Web robar los datos de los usuarios de los navegadores Web.